# Parse Contact details from a block of text

Tags: java, android

Im trying to create a Business card reader

Im having a block of text for example

```
Name 
Head - Business Development
Company Name
# 2/324, ll Floor, Some Road,
Street, City-Zip, State, Country.
Tel : +987654321
Mobile: +123456789
Email : mail@comany.com
Website : www.comany.com
```

I want to parse the details out of this text like name, company name, designation, address. I was able to parse number, email address and website. Can anyone help me with it. I dont want to use any webservices, I want it to be done offline.

Comment: What do you mean by "a block of text"?

Answer (score 0):

You can look at [`StringTokenizer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html).

Answer (score 0):

> I was able to parse number, email address and website

How are you doing it? What problems are you facing in parsing other parts?

If the sequence of contents is not going to change, simply read line by line and parse accordingly.

Comment: i use regex for number, email and websites...the issues with other parts is that the sequence might change